# Filtering Many-to-many field in Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

Im working with the Django REST Framwork and got some issues with the Browsable api. I cannot filter a ManyToMany field so that it only shows the objects which the user is owner of. 
I do manage to filter the the user and filter out m own objects.

In the serializer I have

```
class BidSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        id = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='bid-detail', read_only=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BidSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        request_user = self.context['request'].user
        self.fields['my_items'].queryset  = Item.objects.filter(owner=request_user)
        print(self.fields['my_items'].queryset)
        self.fields['others_items'].queryset = Item.objects.exclude(owner=request_user)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.filter(username=request_user)

    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ('id','comment','user','others_items','my_items','timestamp')
```

The strange thing is that the fields 'user' and 'others_items' are filtered as supposed. While 'my_items' is not filtered but showing all items. However the line containing the print statement shows a correct output. The difference between the fields is that my_items is a ManyToMany field and others_items is a foreign key.

Should it be possible to filter as I like? If not why and how could I filter my choices in a better way?

Comment: can you provide the full serializer class?

Comment: I added the full serializer.

Comment: comma is missing after 'my_items' in fields array. And what is 'OfferObject1'? shouldn't the print statement be `self.fields['my_items'].queryset`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are absolutely right about the typos. I cleaned the script up a little and didn't change those variables correct apparently. The problem is still here. Why font the self.fields['my_items'] change for the many-to-many instance?

Comment: can you try using a custom relation field and override the get_queryset method?

Comment: Can you try this? `self.fields['my_items'].queryset = self.fields['my_items'].queryset.filter(owner=request_user)`

Comment: I tried this but got a "'ManyRelatedField' object has no attribute 'queryset'" error message.

Comment: I wonder where did you read about setting `queryset` on fields. As far as I know rest framework doesn't support what you want not in the way you used (with settings `queryset` attribute on fields) nor in any other way. You should define MethodSerializer and do the rest of filtering and serializing in a method field.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and after inspecting one of my many-to-many fields in my debugger I discovered the `child_relation` property on the many-to-many field which had a `queryset` property. Adding `child_relation` property in front of the queryset worked for me.

I'm also using version 3.8.2 of the Django Rest Framework.

Example:

```
class BidSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='bid-detail', read_only=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BidSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        request_user = self.context['request'].user
        self.fields['my_items'].child_relation.queryset = Item.objects.filter(owner=request_user)
        self.fields['others_items'].child_relation.queryset = Item.objects.exclude(owner=request_user)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.filter(username=request_user)

    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ('id', 'comment', 'user', 'others_items', 'my_items', 'timestamp')
```